# unity Firebase auth state

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement the auth state change with firebase in unity. I dont know if i do it right cuz the doc kinda unclear for me. a good sample of code from your guys would be super respectful from me. this is the link of the doc.   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users?authuser=0
and the title is (Get the currently signed-in user) in the doc. I really need help guys. I dont understand how to use it correctly.I have tried to get help from the firebase dev but haven't got a response. I you guys want a close detail we can chat at discord. Just let me know.  :)

```
DatabaseReference reference;

public static Login instance;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser Player;

bool isServiceAvailable;
bool isAuthenticated;
public Text TEXTName;
public Text TEXTID;
public Text Data;
public Text State;

private User user;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(" I hide the url");
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    State.text = "Checking state";
    InitializeFirebase();
    LogInUser();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}



// Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
void InitializeFirebase()
{
    Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
    AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}

// Track state changes of the auth object.
void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (auth.CurrentUser != Player)
    {
        bool signedIn = Player != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
        if (!signedIn && user != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed out " + Player.UserId);
            State.text = "Sign out";
        }
        Player = auth.CurrentUser;
        if (signedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed in " + Player.UserId);
            State.text = "Sign in";
        }
    }
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
    auth = null;
}

public void SignIn()
{

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(TEXTID.text, TEXTName.text).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }


            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);


    });
}
```

Comment: Firebase automatically persists the authentication state of the user. If you're having trouble implement that, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: I just edit in the code. Sorry i just so new in this page. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: OK. So you're attaching an auth state listener, which is usually the correct way to pick up the authentication state. The state should automatically (asynchronously) be restored when you restart the app. Where are you running this code? And what do all your `Debug.Log` statements print?

Comment: I actually run this test on android mobile , and it doesn't print the sign in string for me at the state.text I run this code at the begin of the game. Do you think i have to replace the (FirebaseUser = Player) with the (FireBaseUser = newUser) at the sign in Function. (Change NewUser --> Player) @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It doesn't print anything @FrankvanPuffelen i just checked in the editor

Comment: That makes no sense. At the very least I'd expect it to print `Setting up Firebase Auth`.

Comment: Good new @FrankvanPuffelen i fix it yesterday with some more testing there and here. but i got some problem with the state that doesn't update everytime i sign out and sign in instead, I have to click on another button or change app and come back to get the result, if you know what i mean. I have  InitializeFirebase(); at the start so its gonna change onece. What do you suggest me to do to get more updates on the User states. Like every time i prees sign out and get immediately change and vice versa. Tanks :)

Comment: forgot to say. that the debug.log does print the SETTING UP FIREBASE AUTH now. But as i said at the statechange funtion the debug.log berly change or print out anything. just once and it take to long time to change on mobile or editor. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

I have good news, [there is a sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/auth/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Auth/UIHandler.cs) and a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0)!

With that said, let me go through a quick impromptu code review:

You are registering the event correctly, and even unregistering in OnDestroy (I find that many folk who are used to `UnityEvent` will omit this step).

I don't think the check against player is doing what you want though. I would make two changes:

First, I'd change `ContinueWith` to `ContinueWithOnMainThread`. If you ever end up making any calls into the `UnityEngine` namespace other than `Debug.Log`, you're asking for trouble.

Next, `FirebaseUser` is implemented in sort of an odd way right now. It references a global static object on the C++ side rather than being a typical PIMPL construct. There are various reasons for this, and it is being worked on, but I wouldn't count on comparisons other than the comparison to null saving you any time right now. This likely won't cause any issues with the code you've posted other than adding a few redundant checks (and `Player.UserId` might be unreliable in your sign out logic), but if you plan to cache `FirebaseUser` for comparison later, it won't work the way you think it will work.

Comment: If you got error when using .ContinueWithOnMainThread, make sure you have using Firebase.Extensions at the top of your file